# automatically determine python exe path and set environment variable accordingly in batch file?

Tags: python

I have Python installed in:

> C:\Python27\python.exe

I need to run Python script from batch file by setting environment variable 
that points to Python exe.
Update: based on response here, i found that install directory in registry has:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath

with Name:Default  and data: C:\Python27\

Now, runing the batch command like this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath" /v Default') DO (
    set CHESSPYTHONPATHv1=%%B)
```

Gives error:

> The System was unable to find specified registry key or value.

Q1) what am i doing wrong?
Q2) This still requires version number to be known by manually looking into registry .
if batch file was to run on another PC, with different Python version, this would fail. How do i specify the registry search path which determines version installed too?
Thanks
sedy

Comment: Check out package "os"; the __path__ attribute for packages is a huge help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you need to do everything in batch. You can try the following:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore" /s ^| findstr InstallPath') do  (
  set key=%%a
  goto :endfor
)
:endfor
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY %key% /ve') do set "CHESSPYTHONPATHv1=%%~bpython.exe"
echo %CHESSPYTHONPATHv1%
```

The first result in the first registry query should contain the InstallPath. The second query retrieves the Python path.

Comment: Thanks ..works like a charm(just had to change little bit for 64 bit Win)